# Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: html

Добрый день. Проблема с кодировкой на сайте, вот картинка -

[image]

Подскажите, что делать, вот сайт http://pokess.ru.

Comment: А у вас "Русский Apache"? Тогда проблема в нём надо изменить конфиг

Comment: Кстати если в браузере насильно поставить WINDOWS-1251 то всё нормально (а если по умолчанию таже кодировка почемуто не работает) странно....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

когда у меня такое было я просто в теги мета кодировку на utf-8 сменил, и у сайта кодировку по умолчанию на нее поменял

Ток мне ещё и файлы переделывать в блокноте, загрузил страницу в блокнот и сохранил как файл с кодировкой utf-8, потом обратно загрузил, и всё нормально стало

Comment: Супер, спс, у меня все файлики в UTF-8 BOM были =)

Answer (score 1):

У вас верстка в utf-8, а БД - в windows-1251. Советую перевести БД на utf-8, пока она не слишком объемная. Сделать это можно, скачав дамп и заменив все строки вида `CHARSET=cp1251` на `CHARSET=utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

и в .htaccess добавьте

```
`AddDefaultCharset cp1251`
```

Comment: Не то и не то не помогло =(

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

2 раза

> CONTENT="text/html;

удали второй, зачем 2 раза-то писать?

2е в какой кодировке сохраняли файлы? все должно быть в windows-1251.

попробуй все написать с маленькой буквы раз стоит

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"[]>
```

этот доктайп.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

скопипасти.

Comment: Ничего не помогло :)

Comment: UTF-8 попробуй

Comment: Проблема в метатеге.Вы неправильно задаете кодировку.У вас контент на cp1251, а вы хотите преобразовывать на utf8. Из за этого.
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
больше ничего не надо.
Мой браузер сейчась генерируеть вот такой вот код по вашей мета теги:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CONTENT=" text="" html;="" charset="UTF-8&quot;">

Comment: Да все уже пробовал, вот по этому задал вопрос

Comment: Vfvtnjd, тогда какую нужно ставить кодировку? Если при windows-1251 тоже такая беда =(

Comment: Да божешь ты мой!

Попробуй прописать в .htaccess

>AddDefaultCharset utf-8 

что тебе сайт покажет. если фигню тогда пропиши

>AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

проблема только тут, больше нигде. И вообще хватит юзать windows-1251 пишите всегда и везде utf-8 много геморроя уйдет сразу, и потом будет проще!

Comment: Да вы попробуйте насильно поставить Windows-1251 тогда срабатывает! Странно...